# Is there anyway to get "glu.h"?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, opengl

I have a very old C++ project using OpenGl and now I want to recompile then upgrade it. But I lost my old OpenGL SDK and so far it hasn't been found yet. I think "glu.h" is outdated and it seems like doesn't appear in newer versions of OpenGL, and I've tried many times but no luck. Could anyone tell me where to get the old package of OpenGL that contains glu.h, in order to help me compile & upgrade my old project properly?

Comment: I can see a `glu.h` file in the Windows SDK headers (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl\glu.h` on my machine). It is also present in version 7.0A of the SDK, don't know about further versions.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - What is the version of your GL? Could you upload your gl as you mentioned?

Comment: I'm pretty sure posting a 18K file here on Stack Overflow will be met with justified criticism :) You can download the SDK and extract the file from there. My `opengl32.dll` reports version `6.1.7600.16385`(seems to be tied to my Windows version).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - I've found glu.h here : www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~cs448/git/trunk/src/include/GL/glu.h - Check and tell me if it's the same.

Comment: @xersi: You've been told "where to get the (new) package that contains glu.h".  Isn't that what you were asking for?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only of interest to the person asking the question

Answer (score 1):

GLU is not part of OpenGL and never got updated beyond the old version that's shipped with practically all Windows compiler suites.

> But I lost my old OpenGL SDK

How can you loose that if there's no such thing? Like I already wrote practically every compiler suite for Windows ships with OpenGL headers and libraries for OpenGL-1.1 (that's what the Windows opengl32.dll ABI natively supports) and GLU.

For anything beyond OpenGL-1.1 you must use the extension mechanism to post-load further functions.